# python async behavior with a queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue, python-asyncio

I am not very good with python async, and I have a task where I have to do something asynchronously with a stack. Here is a pseudocode for what I am trying to accomplish to give a better picture...

```py
done = False
queue = Q()
funcs = [...]  # a long list of functions

async def pusher():
    for func in funcs:
        queue.push(func())
    done = True

# now each function will be async pushed to the queue when it is done
while not done:
    time.sleep(1)
    if not queue.empty():
        items = queue.pop(512)  # pop everything from queue up to a limit of 512 
        process(items)
```

so basically, I want to asyncronously run a list of functions and push them to a queue. Then periodically pop everything (up to a limit) from the queue and further process the return values. The order in which the final processing is done does not matter.

How can I accomplish this? I find every time I dig into asyncio, I get confused and it doesn't work as I would expect

Comment: Asyncio is a cooperative multitasking structure.  It is only useful if you have two or more tasks, such that some of the tasks can continue to execute while other tasks wait for some event to occur.  From your pseudocode I can't see where that would happen in your case.  What two (or more) things are you wanting to run concurrently?

Comment: You throw around a bunch of terms that seem vaguely unrelated to one another. What is it you are dealing with? A stack or a queue? What does "pushing a function to a queue" even mean? Do you really want the callable itself inside the queue or do you mean you want the result it returns to be placed in a queue?

Comment: Instead of getting confused with terminology and pseudo-code, why don't you write _actual_ code -- plain old boring sequential code -- that does what you want and then try to introduce concurrency and present that attempt along with your output/error and the desired output. Because as it stands right now, none of what you wrote makes any sense.